# How do I run NetBeans from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, netbeans

I have installed a JDK + NetBeans bundle from the downloaded .sh file.

Now I have the NetBeans shortcut on my desktop but I can't run NetBeans from the terminal.

When I run:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections
```

NetBeans is not on the list and also I can't find it in the Ubuntu Software Center.

- How do I run it from the terminal and how do I find it in the system?
- When I installed Emacs using `apt-get` it appeared in the main menu and I could launch it from the terminal straight away. How do these two installations differ?

Comment: netbeans is available in the repos, see http://packages.ubuntu.com/netbeans. There is no need to install it from an installer.

Comment: although it's not the latest version :)

Comment: Thanks, I've noticed that. But I wanted to practice and understand installation procedure.

Comment: you don't have to run the install script if you use umake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dpkg is a debian package manager, since you have installed Nebeans by a (presumably local) script, it will not be listed in dpkg -l.

**Retrieve an application's command from it's desktop file:**

When you have an application installed of which you don't know the command, but you do have a desktop file, you can read it from the desktop file's content. The link you have on your desktop *is* a desktop file. Look for a line, starting with "Exec=". What comes after that string is the command you are looking for.

**Make the application available in Dash:**

Normally, applications install a desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` (like emacs does). If a desktop file is located in either that location or in `~/.local/share/applications`, it appears in Dash automatically, so if you copy the desktop file into `~/.local/share/applications`, it will appear in Dash after next log in.

**Open an application by (only) it's binary file name (or not):**

Netbeans did not open on the command `netbeans` because the shell does not know the path to your binary file. If binary files are located in `/usr/bin` (the default path to application's binary files) they will open right away, without the path-prefix. That is the case for example with emacs.

If an application does not install its binary file in `/usr/bin`, there are three possibilities; either the application's desktop file's execute line includes the path to the file, as you can see for example in the execute line of the `file-explorer indicator`'s desktop file: `/opt/indicator-file-explorer/bin/indicator-file-explorer`, or the path to the binary file is added to $PATH (`/etc/environment`), so the shell will search for binary files in that directory too, or the application installs a link to the binary file in `/usr/bin`. All three options do occur, no matter the way an application is installed.

If you installed your application locally, it would be a bad idea to (try to-) create a link to the application's binary file from a global directory, such as `/usr/bin`; other users would be stuck with a dead link, because they have no valid permissions in your home directory. Therefore, the easyest way is to create a local bin directory (`~/bin`) and create a link to the local binary file from that directory (ln -sf). That way you can run your locally installed Netbeans by the single command `netbeans`.

Comment: IMHO there's another difference because emacs can be launched from the Terminal but when I try "netbeans &" I get a message that it's not installed and suggestion to use apt-get install netbeans. Does it mean that apt-get installs add binary file paths to system path but sh installations do not?

Comment: @Alan I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Jacob! That's a very detailed reply. I don't fully understand the last paragraph though. I'd like to start netbeans from terminal. In 'netbeans-8.0.desktop' file I have this line 'Exec=/bin/sh "/home/al1357/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans"' so I did 'sudo ln /home/al1357/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans' in '/usr/bin' directory. Now when I am doing 'netbeans &' I get an error: 'Cannot read cluster file: /usr/etc/netbeans.clusters'. How do I make it work?

Comment: @Alan even if it would work, it is not a good idea to create a link globally (in `usr/bin` to a file or application in the local directory. Other users would be confronted with a "dead" link, since they have no permissions in your local directory. If you create a `bin` directory in your home directory, and place a link there (`ln -sf /home/al1357/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans /home/al1357/bin/netbeans`) it should work after log out / log in. (if I did not mistype anything). Many times it works like that.

Comment: @Alan updated my answer.

Answer (score 11):

**Assuming you downloaded the 7.4 version**

If you installed netbeans from .sh installer **using** `sudo` then the default command to run netbeans is :

```
/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-7.4/bin/netbeans"
```

if you installed netbeans **without** `sudo` then the default command is :

```
~/netbeans-7.4/bin/netbeans
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this might help but what works for me is assuming you are the the current home directory of your user

```
./netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans
```

I installed netbeans by downloading the sh installer from their website. Just curious on how to run netbeans via terminal and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon 
use  `sh netbeans`

for example `~/netbeans-8.2/bin$ sh netbeans`