# How to Execute a program from anywhere in terminal

Tags: startup-applications

How could I execute a program which I downloaded from website and able to execute from $HOME directory or anywhere in terminal?

Comment: if you want to run a locally installed application by its application name (as command) take a look here http://askubuntu.com/a/440247/72216, I think it covers your question. (especially the third paragraph)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say the command you have to run to execute the program is `./path/to/file` and programs name is `xyz`

So create a `.bash_aliases` file in your home directory.
Add the line to the file create a alias for the command.

```
alias xyz="./path/to/file"
```

Save the file and restart terminal.

Next time you can run the program by typing just `xyz`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Additionally I had to execute 2 separate commands: source ~/.bashrc, and, source ~/.bash_aliases; thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817651

Answer (score 2):

If you currently have to run your program by giving the full path (say, `/home/john/someprogram-1.0/someprogram`), you can make it so the program runs by just typing `someprogram`. For this, you need the program to be somewhere in your PATH, which is a list of directories the shell searches for executables that aren't given as full paths.

There are three ways of accomplishing this:

1. Install the program. Depending on where it came from, it probably has installation instructions which will place it in a directory already in the path, like `/usr/bin`. Be aware that installing it this way needs using `sudo`, or having root privileges.
2. Add the directory where the program is right now to your path. You can try this manually by first doing `export PATH=$PATH:/home/john/someprogram-1.0`, then trying to run `someprogram` only, it should work. TO make this change permanent, add the `export` command as shown above to your `.profile` file (this file already exists in your home directory).
3. Put the program in your private `bin` directory. Create `bin` in your home diretory, then copy the `someprogram` file into this directory. This may not work if the program needs access to other data files.

Comment: Hi roadmr, no I can't execute because the tar file I downloaded does not have executable file untill I make one and put into usr/bin/ , thanks for your advise:)